# Custom UISlider with pips ios

Tags: ios, uislider

[image]

Wondering if the above can be created using UISlider? If not, what other ways can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

You can set components of a UISlider, such as the `currentThumbImage` ( see: "Appearance of Sliders"[1](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UISlider.html)).

However, it is almost certainly easier to just re-implement a slider for this much customization. Simply use background `UIImageView` with the scale image, and then add a separate `UIView` (or `UIImageView`) for the arrow. Finally, attach a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to the arrow view to allow a user translate the view vertically.

Answer (score 0):

You can change a lot in the appearance of a `UISlider` like setting the thumb to a red arrow. You can also replace the background image with the inches ruler and with different rulers for the different device types and display sizes.

The one thing that I don't see is that you turn the slider to work vertically. I know them only working left to right.

If I'm right, your only chance is to have a ruler as background image and a view that contains the arrow and a label with the actual value. That whole view can be pawned and tapped using Gesture Listener.